# What are variables with dollar sign ($) like $TERM and $PATH

Tags: terminal

What is the purpose of `$TERM` and `$PATH`? I always see posts saying you need to edit these but I never see any file name or directory that is titled either one.

Answer (score 0):

They are system variables.

To check the value of the variable: `echo $PATH`

And to set the variable: `export PATH=$PATH:/place/with/the/file`

Ref.: https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux